# convert multiple column values based on conditions on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have below dataframe:

```
d = {'MIN_VALUE': [None, None, None, 1, None, None, None], 'MAX_VALUE': [None, None, None, None, None,2, None], 
     'OPERATOR': ['<', '>', '=', '>',None, "<", "="], 'RAW_VALUE':[1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7],
    'MIN_UNITS_' : [None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'MAX_UNITS' : [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    "RAW_UNITS" : ['mol/L','mol/L','mol/L','mol/L','mol/L', 'mol/L', 'mol/L'
                               ]}
```

[image]

and I need to convert this table to below table:

[image]

Rule:

- when min_value and max_value are Nan:

  - if we have < operator, max_value= raw_value and max_units = raw_units
  - if we have > operator, min_value= raw_value and min_units = raw_units
  - if we have = operator, min_value & max_value = raw_value and min_units & max_units= raw_units

```
def convert_to_range_values(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    non_ranged_indices = pd.isna(data["MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"]) & pd.isna(
        data["MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])

    data.loc[(data["RAW_VALUE_OPERATOR"] == "<") & (pd.isna(data["MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])) & (pd.isna(
        data["MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])), "MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"] = data["RAW_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"]

    data.loc[(data["RAW_VALUE_OPERATOR"] == "<") & (pd.isna(data["MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])) & (pd.isna(
        data["MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])), "MAX_VALUE_UNITS_STANDARDIZED"] = data["RAW_UNITS_STANDARDIZED"]
    
    data.loc[(data["RAW_VALUE_OPERATOR"] == ">") & (pd.isna(data["MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])) & (pd.isna(
        data["MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])), "MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"] = data["RAW_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"]

    data.loc[(data["RAW_VALUE_OPERATOR"] == ">") & (pd.isna(data["MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])) & (pd.isna(
        data["MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])), "MIN_VALUE_UNITS_STANDARDIZED"] = data["RAW_UNITS_STANDARDIZED"]

    data.loc[(data["RAW_VALUE_OPERATOR"] == "=") & (pd.isna(data["MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])) & (pd.isna(
        data["MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])), "MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"] = data["RAW_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"]

    data.loc[(data["RAW_VALUE_OPERATOR"] == "=") & (pd.isna(data["MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])) & (pd.isna(
        data["MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])), "MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"] = data["RAW_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"]

    data.loc[(data["RAW_VALUE_OPERATOR"] == "=") & (pd.isna(data["MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])) & (pd.isna(
        data["MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])), "MAX_VALUE_UNITS_STANDARDIZED"] = data["RAW_UNITS_STANDARDIZED"]

    data.loc[(data["RAW_VALUE_OPERATOR"] == "=") & (pd.isna(data["MIN_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])) & (pd.isna(
        data["MAX_VALUE_STANDARDIZED"])), "MIN_VALUE_UNITS_STANDARDIZED"] = data["RAW_UNITS_STANDARDIZED"]

    return non_ranged_indices, data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def conv(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['MIN_VALUE']) and pd.isnull(row['MAX_VALUE']):
        operator = row['OPERATOR']
        if operator == '<' or operator == '=':
            row['MAX_VALUE']= row['RAW_VALUE']
            row['MAX_UNITS'] = row['RAW_UNITS']
        if operator == '>' or operator == '=':
            row['MIN_VALUE'] = row['RAW_VALUE']
            row['MIN_UNITS_'] = row['RAW_UNITS']
    return row
     
df = df.apply(conv, axis = 1)
```

which gives:

```
   MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE OPERATOR  RAW_VALUE MIN_UNITS_ MAX_UNITS RAW_UNITS
0        NaN        1.0        <          1       None     mol/L     mol/L
1        2.0        NaN        >          2      mol/L      None     mol/L
2        3.0        3.0        =          3      mol/L     mol/L     mol/L
3        1.0        NaN        >          4       None      None     mol/L
4        NaN        NaN     None          5       None      None     mol/L
5        NaN        2.0        <          6       None      None     mol/L
6        7.0        7.0        =          7      mol/L     mol/L     mol/L
```